# Angular animate removeClass does not work

Tags: angularjs, removeclass, ng-animate

`$animate.removeClass` doesn't add `visible-remove` & `visible-remove-active` classes during deleting `visible` class. Although, `$animate.addClass` works fine.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDir', [
    '$rootScope',
    '$animate',
    function ($rootScope, $animate) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ($scope, element) {

                $rootScope.$on('someEvent', function (event, showMenu) {
                    if (showMenu) {
                        $animate.addClass(element, 'visible');
                    }
                    else {
                        $animate.removeClass(element, 'visible');
                    }
                    $scope.$apply();
                });
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: In which context to you execute the code above, means is it part of a directive? Is it wrapped within an event like `click`? Please edit your question and provide more information.

Comment: Also you usually provide a callback to `$apply` and put the code inside.

Comment: I've tried `$apply(function() {...})`, but got the same result.

Comment: Right, I think you don't even need the `$apply`. Can you provide a Plunker?

Comment: Do you mean this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/)? It is not used in the project.

Comment: `$apply` actually helps with `addClass`. I don't understand why it has no effect on `removeClass`, as both methods are just wrappers over `setClass`.